# How to print dlsym() variable?

Tags: c, linux, dll, printf, dlsym

I writes my own lib:

```
struct utsname Lib;

char *s(){
    uname(&Lib);
    return Lib.sysname;
}
```

When I want to print my system name:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    void *lib=dlopen(".../Mylib.so",RTLD_LAZY);

    if(!lib)
        dlerror();
    else{
        char *a;
        int opt;
        while((opt = getopt (argc, argv, "sn")) != -1){
            switch(opt){
                case 's':
                    a= (char*)dlsym(lib, "s");
                    printf("test: %s", a);
                break;
            }
        }

    }   

    if(lib)
        dlclose(lib);

return 0;
}
```

I get something like:

```
UH▒▒H▒=▒
```

**I think that is caused by wrong casting my char a.** When I tested it in one file, char assigned to the dlsym works fine.

Makefile:

```
main: mainname.c
    gcc -c -fPIC lib.c
    gcc -shared -fPIC -o lib.so lib.c
    gcc -o main mainname.c -ldl
```

Comment: You don't call the function. Cast the result of `dlsym()` to a function pointer and then call it.

Comment: `char (*ptr_fun)()`
`*(void**)(&ptr_fun)=dlsym(lib, "s")`
`printf("test: %s", (*ptr_fun))`
@cremno If you mean this, this solution gives me again UH▒▒H▒=▒

Comment: You still don't call the function. `a = ((char*(*)(void))dlsym(lib, "s"))();` could be a correct way. The `()` here call it.

Comment: @cremno: You might like to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

As cremno mentioned, you didn't call the function.

```
            char *(*s)();
            …
                s = dlsym(lib, "s");
                printf("test: %s", s());
```

would be a somewhat more readable way to do it.